# Matlab code has a systematic error

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

I have the following code to calculate the number of real eigenvectors of a normally distributed matrix:

```
x=zeros(1,100); %make an 1x100 array of 0's
n = 1000;

for i=1:100
   Nr=0;
   a=normrnd(0,1,n); % make a nxn matrix N(0,1)
   C=eig(a);  %make c the eigen values of a
   for k=1:n
      if (isreal(C(k))==1) %loop through each value of c andcheck if it is real
          Nr=Nr+1; %if it is real increment Nr
      end
   end
   x(i)=Nr/sqrt(n);
end
Estimation_Of_C=mean (x)
Estimation_Of_Error=std (x)
```

According to http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/homepage/papers/howmany.pdf this should be equal to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ however for whichever value of $n$ I use (bigger and smaller than 1000), I more often than not get `Estimation_ofC`> 0.8 so I appear to have a small systematic error.

Am I simply wanting the code to be too precise or do I have an actual error in my code?

Comment: Please unaccept my answer and go with the one form @themaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value $\sqrt \frac{2}{\pi}$ is in the limit when $n\rightarrow \infty$. If you use the asymptotic formula instead
$$\frac{N_r}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+O(\frac{1}{n})$$
in your case
$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}} \approx  0.8136959$

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that the issue is with your use of `isreal`. `eig` is an iterative solver, which means that it is possible that some eigenvalues are being computed with a very small but non-zero imaginary part due to truncation error. For instance

```
isreal(4+1e-12i)
```

will return false.

Instead, I would condition a check on the complex part of each eigenvalue using `imag`. Rather than saying `isreal(C(k)) == 1`, I would do something like:

```
epsilon = 1e-10;
if abs(imag(C(k)) < epsilon
    ...
end
```

This might improve your results.

Comment: Note: I'm not sitting in front of a MATLAB install, so I can't verify your code. But if I remember tomorrow morning, I'll give it a run and see if I can get some improvement.

Comment: You are close with the issue concerning the `isreal()` function. It only checks for type and not non-zero imaginary part. For instance, `isreal(complex(1))` is false even though $1\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Ah, good call. I don't recall the subtleties of the mechanics of it. I almost never use type checking functions in MATLAB anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `Nr` to zero at the start of each iteration. Though you can make this moot by avoiding the inner loop completely. Also note that `isreal( complex(1) )` will return `false` and not true. See `help isreal` for an explanation. Also, the numerical issue is valid, so using something the like following is probably the proper way to go about it (though using angle off the real axis might be better):

```
x=zeros(1,100); %make an 1x100 array of 0's
n = 1000;
for i=1:100
   a=normrnd(0,1,n); % make a nxn matrix N(0,1)
   C=eig(a);  %make c the eigen values of a
   Nr = length( find( abs(imag(C)) < 10*eps ) );
   x(i)=Nr/sqrt(n);
end
Estimation_Of_C=mean (x)
Estimation_Of_Error=std (x)

Estimation_Of_C =

         0.813337814195307


Estimation_Of_Error =

         0.131508727674423
```

Here is the histogram for 1000 iterations:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the improvment of the code, but the problem is that C should be equal to 0.797885-ish but whenever I run the code I always get slightly above 0.8

Comment: I got $~\approx 40$ when I ran your code since `Nr` continued to accumulate every iteration.

Comment: I typed the `Nr` in the wrong place to begin with, I have just changed it. But on the actual code I get (0.85-0.8) which is too high

Comment: @user2962956 Point taken. I just ran it for 1000 iterations and got ~0.8167. I also added the histogram to my answer and we see that $x$ is not normally distributed, so maybe more iterations or larger $n$ is required.